# Trying to send a javascript array of objects to my other php file where I can decode it and save the elements to my database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, object

Hi I have searched everywhere and although some questions and answers have helped I still cannot seem to get my array of objects to send to my PHP file (body_parts_submit.php).

Basically, I have created 6 arrays and within them they have objects its complicated but I want every body part, every exercise every set and rep and weight value to be different so I can distinguish between them later on. 
The success function never seems to run when I run the code in a browser, so it could be the way I've structured the arrays or the javascript itself. Any help would be much appreciated I've been sitting on this problem for days.

```
$("#add-cart").click(function(){


            var numBodyParts = parseInt($("input[name='number_bodypart']").val());

            var bodyParts = new Array();
            bodyParts[0] = "Body Parts:";

            var exerciseNames = new Array();
            exerciseNames[0] = new Array();
            exerciseNames[0][0] = "Exercise names:";

            var numOfSets = new Array();
            numOfSets[0] = new Array();
            numOfSets[0][0] = "Number of sets per exercise:";

            var setNum = new Array();
            setNum[0] = new Array();
            setNum[0][0] = new Array();
            setNum[0][0][0] = "Set Number:";

            var repValue = new Array();
            repValue[0] = new Array();
            repValue[0][0] = new Array();
            repValue[0][0][0] = "Number of reps:";

            var weightValue = new Array();
            weightValue[0] = new Array();
            weightValue[0][0] = new Array();
            weightValue[0][0][0] = "Amount of weight:";



                for(b=1;b<=numBodyParts;b++){
                    bodyParts[b] = {bodypart:document.getElementById("bodypart_select"+b).value};
                    var numExercises = document.getElementById("table"+b).rows.length;
                    exerciseNames[b] = new Array();
                    numOfSets[b] = new Array();
                    setNum[b] = new Array();
                    repValue[b] = new Array();
                    weightValue[b] = new Array();

                    for(e = 1; e<=numExercises;e++){
                        exerciseNames[b][e] = {exercise:document.getElementById("exercise_"+b+"_"+e).value};
                        numOfSets[b][e] = {numofsets:document.getElementById("number_set_"+b+"_"+e).value};
                        var numofSets = document.getElementById("set_"+b+"_"+e).rows.length;
                        setNum[b][e] = new Array();
                        repValue[b][e] = new Array();
                        weightValue[b][e] = new Array();

                        for(s=1; s<=numofSets; s++){
                            setNum[b][e][s] = {setnum:s};
                            repValue[b][e][s] = {reps:document.getElementById(b+"_reps_"+e+"_"+s).value};
                            weightValue[b][e][s] = {weight:document.getElementById(b+"_weight_"+e+"_"+s).value};


                        }
                    }
                }

            var test1 = JSON.stringify(bodyParts[1]);
            var test2 = JSON.stringify(exerciseNames);
            var test3 = JSON.stringify(numOfSets);
            var test4 = JSON.stringify(setNum);
            var test5 = JSON.stringify(repValue[1][2][2]);
            var test6 = JSON.stringify(weightValue[1][1][1]);

            console.log(test1);
            console.log(test2);
            console.log(test3);
            console.log(test4);
            console.log(test5);
            console.log(test6);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "body_parts_submit.php",
                    data: {bodyparts:JSON.stringify(bodyParts[1])},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("Success");
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.message);
                    },
                    dataType: "json"                    
            });
    });
```

Below is my php file - body_parts_submit.php

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["bodyparts"]);

if(isset($_POST["bodyparts"]))
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST["bodyparts"]);
    echo('{"reason": "'.$data.'"}');
}
else{
    echo ('{"reason": "failure"}');
}
```

Comment: Does it run when you send nothing or hard-coded data for testing? Does the post request execute and `body_parts_submit.php` receives anything at all?

Comment: `print_r($data);` and you can't echo it.

Comment: Just put all your arrays into a `var bigArray` and pass `data: bigArray,` and jQuery will do all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: In PHP do a `file_put_contents('param.txt', print_r($_POST,1));` and it will show you what the data in `$_POST` looks like when it arrives to your PHP script